# Typecheck weirdness with lists of lists

Tags: haskell, types

I am not a Haskell pro. Today I had a somewhat bizarre experience with the type system today. The second line of this will cause a type error. The problem is the `maxdiag (as:bs:cs:ds)` bit of the second line:

```
maxdiag ((a:as):(b:bs):(c:cs):(d:ds):xs) len =
  maximum [a*(bs !! 0)*(cs !! 1)*(ds !! 2), maxdiag (as:bs:cs:ds) (len-1)]
```

It fails with the following error:

```
Occurs check: cannot construct the infinite type: a0 = [a0]
Expected type: [[a0]]
  Actual type: [a0]
In the second argument of `(:)', namely `ds'
In the second argument of `(:)', namely `cs : ds'
```

When I change the offending part of the second line to `maxdiag (as:bs:cs:ds:xs)`, so that it reads

```
maxdiag ((a:as):(b:bs):(c:cs):(d:ds):xs) len =
  maximum [a*(bs !! 0)*(cs !! 1)*(ds !! 2), maxdiag (as:bs:cs:ds:xs) (len-1)]
```

... then there is no error. Similarly, if I replace it with `maxdiag (as:bs:cs:(ds:xs))` it succeeds. My questions are

1. What does this error mean?
2. Why has it occurred?
3. Why do these two seemingly different things fix it?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The thing to remember is that `(:)` has the type `a -> [a] -> [a]`, so its first argument is an element, while the second argument is a list with that element type. If the elements are themselves lists, this becomes `[a] -> [[a]] -> [[a]]`.

In your example, `as`, `bs`, `cs` and `ds` all have type `[a]`, while `xs` has type `[[a]]`, so `cs:ds` is an error while `ds:xs` is well-typed.

The reason for that particular error message is that when you try to use `(:)` on two things of the same type `b`, the only way that would work is if `b` was the same type as `[b]`, but that would be an infinite type which is not allowed.

For the other question, the `(:)` operator is right-associative, so `as:bs:cs:ds:xs` is the same as `as:(bs:(cs:(ds:xs)))` and also `as:bs:cs:(ds:xs)`.

Answer (score 5):

The error:

```
A.hs:2:63:
    Occurs check: cannot construct the infinite type: a0 = [a0]
    Expected type: [[a0]]
      Actual type: [a0]
    In the second argument of `(:)', namely `ds'
    In the second argument of `(:)', namely `cs : ds'
```

means you have recursive constraints on the type, which is illegal. I.e. your type `a` has to be both `a` and `[a]`.

The "[occurs check](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Occurs_check)" is the technical name for the part of [the type checking algorithm](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hindley%E2%80%93Milner#Algorithm_W) that is executing at this point. The "occurs check" prevents the construction of infinitely recursive types.

In my experience failing the occurs check with list-like errors means you're mixing up `(:)` and `(++)`. That is you're sometimes using a value as a list element, and sometimes as a list itself.

In this case, it is the use of `(:)` in the expression `as:bs:cs:ds`.
Probably you mean something like:

```
[as,bs,cs,ds]++xs
```

Note that your code is pretty complicated - it makes lots of assumptions about the number and shape of the elements in the list that are very unlikely to be true at all times. I'd be very scared of this code. It would be much safer to:

- use pattern matching to rule out the other cases (e.g. empty lists, missing elements)
- replace the indexing (!!) with pattern matching.

and think hard about how you can simplify your algorithm.

Comment: I didn't include any other context about the function (i.e., other patterns) specifically because I didn't want to complicate the real question, which is not about those patterns.But it's not part of a robust program or anything, I'm just messing around with the type system to get the hang of the errors. I would never actually write code like this. :P